# Disabling a static tab with Angular UI Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to set a tab to be disabled in a Angular Ui-bootstrap 2.0 tabset.

In the example on their site, the one they are enabling and disabling (with a button) is a dynamic tab (an ng-repeat). I tried that, it works.

I am trying to disable a Tab in a set that's not created with an ng-repeat, and it does not seem to work.  I have hard-coded the disabled property.  I tried using a simple "true" and a controller property.  The tab remains selectable.

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="1" heading="Another static title">
   Consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="2" heading="Still another static title" disabled="amDisabled">
    Recusandae
  </uib-tab>
```

where `$scope = amDisabled = true`

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VQZMs7h7203r83QSI7jG?p=preview).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the `disable` attribute not `disabled`

Here is the same [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dMyfKdqvxRLkR1VvbjXY?p=preview) with the `disable` attribute

It's an easy mistake to make!